# RVM installs of Sass/Compass in wrong/different directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, rvm, compass-sass

I set up Sass and Compass on my mac and everything works fine. I've not gone to install these and upload my work to my linux (CentOS I think) testing server. I've installed ruby via:

`curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Then I ran `gem install sass` and `gem install compass`. All seems good at this point and both installed fine, confirmed by checking their -v versions.

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                             
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                                                
  '/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/bin/compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--images-dir' '/home/mysitefolder/public_html/integration/app/../web/images' '--config' '/tmp/  
  assetic_compassFPgfWV' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compassJnTN1B.scss'                                                         

  Error Output:                                                                                                                                   
  sh: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

I think the problem is that `/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/bin/compass` don't exists after install. `which sass` and `which compass` tell me that they are installed in:

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/sass`

and

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/compass`

How do i change this to be in `/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/bin/compass` instead? I'm guessing I could point to them file paths but then it would break when ever I update to a newer version wouldn't it?